# WebAPI Controller method not showing in swagger

Tags: c#, azure, swagger

C# Azure Web Service API

I created a web service that I'm using a mobile app to hook up to.  I created a default CRUD controller in the controllers container and all of those methods show (and works well) in swagger.

I added a new method in the controller to perform a task not covered in the CRUD and it's not showing in swagger.  Example:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> test(tblProfileList test)
    {
        // just testing to see if this method shows in swagger
        tblProfileList ProfileList = await db.tblProfileLists.FindAsync("10");
        return NotFound(); // yes, 10 will never be found but that's not the point of this test
    }
```

Even if I modify an existing CRUD method in the controller, it will end up removing it from swagger.  It seems like a mapping issue of some sort but I can't see where the methods are registered other than in the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Why can't I change the names of the methods or add a new method in an existing controller?  Or should I say, how can I add a method in and have it show in swagger?

Comment: You should be able to add new methods easily, but it is hard to answer this without more information.
Can you start by telling us what routes you have defined and what other methods you have?

Answer (score 1):

Add the [Route] attribute to the method. 
Also make sure that your controller name is actually suffixed with .....Controller.

Comment: I accidentally had `...Controllers` (smh)

Answer (score 1):

Who call your public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) function?

From what I know you need to create Global.asax file
After adding you will get file that look like this:

```
public class Global
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Just add this line on `Application_Start` function and then the Register function will actually be called

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(YouClassName.Register);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the method to GetTest() :

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTest(tblProfileList test)
    {
        // just testing to see if this method shows in swagger
        tblProfileList ProfileList = await db.tblProfileLists.FindAsync("10");
        return NotFound(); // yes, 10 will never be found but that's not the point of this test
    }
```